# In PyCharm: "Unused local variable..." using multiple JavaScript template files

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm for my Django project and In my file `product_header_js.html`:

```
<script>
    {% include 'global_variables.js' %}
    {% include 'update_scene_function.js' %}
    ...
    // I may use variables in here or in update_scene_function.js
</script>
```

I would like to use variables in `global_variables.js` in my `update_scene_function.js` file and `product_header_js.html` file. PyCharm lets me do this, but gives me the error `Unused local variable...` in `global_variables.js` and all my variables are greyed out because PyCharm doesn't think they are being used. Is there anyway to fix PyCharm?

Comment: It's the first time I saw this. Can you use `{% include %}` to include javascript files in django? Is there any reference that explained this?

Comment: It works for me, because these `.js` files are in the templates directory, but PyCharm has trouble knowing which variables get used. This article (https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-template-languages.html) shows you how to add JavaScript as a template file type. This stops the template tag errors.

Answer (score 0):

So what generated this question was me trying to modularize my JavaScript code, but it looks like I might have to just deal with the PyCharm warnings. Even when I add JavaScript as a template file type, PyCharm's JavaScript interpreter still gives me warnings (not Django template tag warnings) when I do something like this:

```
{% if something %}
    var my_var = "a";
{% else %}
    var my_var = "b";
{% endif %}
```

It'll say `Duplicate declaration`. And when I reference a variable not in the current template file or when I don't use a variable declared in the current template, PyCharm complains.

So in summary, you can do this, but PyCharm will complain and the `CTRL + clicking` to jump to declarations doesn't work.

One of my follow-up questions would be, if you can tolerate the PyCharm warnings, is `including` JavaScript files better performing than multiple external JavaScript files (). I would think `including` would perform better most of the time (except if most of your traffic is returning visitors where you could use external JavaScript files and leverage caching).

Comment: You can suppress PyCharm warnings with e.g. `//noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols`. I do this in my .js files that are included via `<script>`. Wish there was a more glamorous way.